# simple python module in gnuradio fails "Expression None is invalid for type 'real'"

Tags: python, gnuradio

I have a simple python module to iterate over a few frequencies in a list. For me this should be simple but it's not working within grc.

`Expression None is invalid for type 'real'`

If I run the module manually it returns f as expected. Within grc the flow fails. If I simply return a frequency, it also works.

What did I miss here?

```py
# this module will be imported in the into your flowgraph
fc = [438100000, 438200000]
fs = len(fc)

i = 1
f = fc[i]

def sweeper(prob_lvl):
    global fc, fs, i
    if prob_lvl:
        f = fc[i]
        i += 1
    if i == fs:
        i = 1
    # return int('438000000') ### this works
    return int(f)  ### this doesnt (block says: Expression None is invalid for type 'real')
```

Comment: At least the second if should be `if i==fs:`, no?

Comment: Als not that the values in `fc` are ints and not string as might be implied from the comment

Comment: Python errors contain a backtrace, i.e., they tell you where exactly (and in what call chain) things went wrong. Please copy and paste the **full** error message (into the question).

Comment: @tomron ok, that was me while trying things. you are right, I edited that

Comment: also, almost certain you don't want a global-scoped variables like your `fc`, `fs`, `i` and `f`; maybe you'd want to encapsulate this into a class (all of this is python basics, not so much GNU Radio, by the way). As a rule of thumb, you *never* want to use the `global` keyword, it is a pretty clear indicator of a design bug.

Comment: @MarcusMüller and that was exactly the "design bug" that prevented thing from running. running grc in debug mode mentioned that I didnt assign f within the function. Putting it in the globals helps - but it's bad design like you said. Sorry, still learning :)

Answer (score 0):

Lesson learned:
don't use globals

If you use globals, don't forget to include everything needed, "f" in this case.

running gnuradio-companion --log debug helps

Comment: More a comment than an answer.